# Estou com um problema em uma section

Tags: html, css

Estou com um problema em deixar uma section com os icons na horizontal, ele estão na vertical e não consigo arrumar ..

codigo html completo:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One');
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: helvetica;
}



header{
 z-index: 5;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: #fff;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
}

nav{
 display: table;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
 height: 40px;
 -webkit-transition: margin-left .5s;
}

ul{
 margin-right: 850px;
 display: block;
 float: right;
 list-style: none;
}

ul li{
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;

}

ul a{
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: color .1s;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    color: #fff;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}

.parallax-targeta{
    height: 700px;
    background: transparent center fixed;

}


.parallax-targetb{
    height: 300px;
    background: transparent center fixed;

}


.middle{
    min-height: 400px;
 background: transparent;
}
.slide{
 background-image: url(../img/2853636-firewatch-wallpapers.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 700px;
}

iframe{
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
}

    .sec-services {
    background: #14B97D;
    padding-top:70px;
    padding-bottom:70px;
    color:#fff;
    }
    #services h3{
    padding-bottom:100px;
    }
    .sec-services h2,
    .sec-services p {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .sec-services{
    font-size:1.1em;
    }
    .sec-services i {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 45px;
    }

    .sec-services .fa-paint-brush {
    width: 64px;
    }

    .sec-services .fa-code {
    width: 68px
    }

    .sec-services h2 {
    margin: 1em 0;
    }

    p 
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    }

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 1em;
}


.intro .container, .features .container, .portfolio .container, .contact .container {
  padding: 5em 0;
}

.intro, .features, .portfolio, .contact {
  text-align: center;
}

.intro {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  color: #fff;
}

.intro a, .intro a:hover, .intro a:focus, .intro a:active, .intro a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.features img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.features .col-3 {
  margin: 3em auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>efecto scroll en menu</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/index_style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="dependencies/parallax.js-1.4.2/parallax.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src='js/script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Inicio</li></a>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Videos</li></a>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Im&aacute;genes</li></a>

    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Youtube</li></a>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Nosotros</li></a>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Contacto</li></a>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>

 <main class="content">
  
  <section class="slide">
   <div class="content">
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/sVxBaRYnjgE?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;nologo=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=light&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;controls=0" width="690" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
 <section class="services">
   <div id="services" class="sec-services">
  <div class="container cf">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-paint-brush"></i>
      <h2 class="h3">1323</h2>
          <p>Cfaefaekfneiafjieajfaei.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-code"></i>
          <h2 class="h3">1323</h2>
          <p>Cfaefaekfneiafjieajfaei.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-tablet"></i>
      <h2 class="h3">1323</h2>
          <p>Cfaefaekfneiafjieajfaei.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
  
  
  <div class="container-fluid features" id="skills">
  <div class="container cf">
    <h2>Skills &amp; Experience</h2>
    <div class="col-XS-4">
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/oi5es3fkx/icon_cloud.png" alt="">
      <h3>Cloud Computing</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda modi maiores eum commodi soluta, blanditiis voluptates ea eos, cim! Neque.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-XS-4">
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/jxj8d5vvl/icon_coding.png" alt="">
      <h3>Expert Coding</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda modi maiores eum commodi soluta, blanditiis voluptates ea eos, cim! Neque.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-XS-4">
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/citwksa01/icon_graph.png" alt="">
      <h3>Data Analysis</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda modi maiores eum commodi soluta, blanditiis voluptates ea eos, cim! Neque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  
  
<div class="parallax-targeta section-0" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/4.jpeg">
    </div>
<!-- section 2 starts-->
<!-- section 3 starts-->
<div class="parallax-targetb section-1" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/3.jpeg"></div>
<!-- section 4 starts-->


</main>
<script>
$(window).on("load resize", function(e){
   var vid = $("iframe");

   if(e.type == "load"){
      var vid_w_tag = vid.attr("width");
      var vid_h_tag = vid.attr("height");
      proporcao = vid_w_tag/vid_h_tag;
      vid.attr("width","100%")
      .css('max-width', vid_w_tag+'px');
   }

   var vid_w = vid.width();
   vid.attr('height',vid_w/proporcao);
}); 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

como da pra ver no snippet tou com problema em uma section :

```
    <div class="container-fluid features" id="skills">
  <div class="container cf">
    <h2>Skills &amp; Experience</h2>
    <div class="col-XS-4">
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/oi5es3fkx/icon_cloud.png" alt="">
      <h3>Cloud Computing</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda modi maiores eum commodi soluta, blanditiis voluptates ea eos, cim! Neque.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-XS-4">
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/jxj8d5vvl/icon_coding.png" alt="">
      <h3>Expert Coding</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda modi maiores eum commodi soluta, blanditiis voluptates ea eos, cim! Neque.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-XS-4">
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/citwksa01/icon_graph.png" alt="">
      <h3>Data Analysis</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda modi maiores eum commodi soluta, blanditiis voluptates ea eos, cim! Neque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

o css dela:

```
.intro .container, .features .container, .portfolio .container, .contact .container {
  padding: 5em 0;
}

.intro, .features, .portfolio, .contact {
  text-align: center;
}

.intro {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  color: #fff;
}

.intro a, .intro a:hover, .intro a:focus, .intro a:active, .intro a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.features img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.features .col-3 {
  margin: 3em auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Podes fazer um JSFiddle ou plunker para simular? Não me parece errado... E claro, se você estiver acessando de um tablet/celular, ele vai respeitar o `col-sm` e vai ficar na vertical.

Comment: @Jackson opa bro https://jsfiddle.net/n787z9fv/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7hvhcm9t/ esse aq tb deu mesmo jeito :(

Comment: Cara posta o <head> do seu site, ou de preferência o HTML inteiro! Acho que pode ser a versão do CDN do Bootstrap que vc está usando.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/77vf582f/ ta ai mano o html completo.

Comment: Gabriel editei minha resposta com a parte dos Skill logo no início vc  vai ver, é só copiar pra sua página. mas devido o tamanho das imagens em telas pequena pode quebrar o layout, ai é melhor jogar cada um para uma linha mesmo...

Comment: E ai jovem deu certo agora?

Comment: deu certissimo broo, agr eu entendi com os exemplos q vc me passou man!